# How can I solve this problem: SSH Unknown error

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

- When I connect to remote server using VS code, I got this OUTPUT:

```
[12:00:38.322] Log Level: 2
[12:00:38.344] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+10.101.169.215", attempt 1
[12:00:38.345] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[12:00:38.345] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[12:00:38.345] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[12:00:38.346] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[12:00:38.346] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[12:00:38.346] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[12:00:38.346] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[12:00:38.346] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[12:00:38.346] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[12:00:38.347] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[12:00:38.347] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[12:00:38.347] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[12:00:38.347] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[12:00:38.347] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[12:00:38.347] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[12:00:38.348] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[12:00:38.353] VS Code version: 1.75.0
[12:00:38.353] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.96.0
[12:00:38.353] win32 x64
[12:00:38.354] SSH Resolver called for host: 10.101.169.215
[12:00:38.354] Setting up SSH remote "10.101.169.215"
[12:00:38.360] Using commit id "e2816fe719a4026ffa1ee0189dc89bdfdbafb164" and quality "stable" for server
[12:00:38.365] Install and start server if needed
[12:00:43.867] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[12:00:43.895] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[12:00:43.900] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 50865 "10.101.169.215" bash
[12:00:43.903] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[12:00:44.121] > ssh: connect to host 10.101.169.215 port 22: Unknown error
> ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[12:00:44.121] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[12:00:44.136] > 过程试图写入的管道不存在。
[12:00:45.393] "install" terminal command done
[12:00:45.394] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe过程试图写入的管道不存在。
[12:00:45.394] Received install output: ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe过程试图写入的管道不存在。
[12:00:45.394] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[12:00:45.396] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (c:\Users\nalan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:584147)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\nalan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:582761)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\nalan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:680758)
    at async c:\Users\nalan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:643114
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\nalan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:646432)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\nalan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:644164)
    at async c:\Users\nalan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:721750
[12:00:45.400] ------
```

I also have an window told me that:

- Could not establish connection to "10.101.169.215".

TRY:

1. I had tried to install vscode-server manually, but no effect
2. I delete the file .ssh/known_hosts, nothing happened.
3. I think the problem maybe my OpneSSH, so I run ssh username@10.101.169.215 in
   ,got

```
"ssh: connect to host 10.101.169.215 port 22: Unknown error"
```

4. I have been searching solution about "ssh: connect to host 10.101.169.215 port 22: Unknown error", but found nothing.
   What should I do to connect my remote server sucessfully ?
   Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the relevant information of the server in the %USERPROFILE%.ssh\known_hosts file and the %USERPROFILE%.ssh\config file and try to reconnect